# Choice of metric for multilabel classification problem

Tags: machine-learning, classification, metrics, multilabel-classification

I have a multilabel classification problem with K labels. Ideally, I'm looking to train a model to maximize the exact match accuracy, but I know that this kind of metric is not suitable for this kind of task.

I have a function that takes the output of the predictions, e.g. `y_pred= [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]` and then computes a value `f_pred`.

Instead of trying to getting an exact match from the predicted values, I want to introduce a metric such that the mean absolute error (MAE), defined as,

```
MAE = (f_true-f_pred)/f_true*100
```

is minimized. Any suggestions on how I can relate the problem of minimizing the MAE to the original problem of multilabel classification.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you knoww about your objects ? Do they have a lot of features ?

Comment: The dataset has 64 features, for the number of examples itself they are generated using simulations, currently, the size of the dataset is 10000 but I can generate more if needed.

Comment: And what do you call `f_true` and `f_out` ?

Comment: Sorry, `f_true` is the value of the function when I use the true labels, and `f_pred` (not `f_out`, I've corrected that) is is the value of the function when I use the predicted labels.